# Vertical and horizontal align a div without sizes

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a `div` with both `width` and `height` set to `auto` become centered on the screen, both vertically and horizontally. Here's the current CSS I've done, please any help.

```
 #popup {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    display: table;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 650px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

**CSS**

```
#popup {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    font-family:Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    display: table;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 650px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/24/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/13/

HTML

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="div">
            <p>THIS IS CONTENT</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.page {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.content {
    display: table-row;
}

.div {
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```